# HTML Table Images Stretching too big

Tags: html, image, css-tables

I can't figure this out... when I am adding images inside of a **table's td** element the images are stretching too be so large and do not seem be effected by the styling of

```
td > img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

or it is using some parent element that it is not supposed to

The **td** element is only about **150px** by **200px** and the image will turn out to be about  **3000+ px** by **1000+ px**.

why is the styling not taking effect how I would imagine to fill the **td** element? What am I doing wrong? A sample of what I am trying to create is here http://jsfiddle.net/nf071590/dk12c61o/1/ ; which works fine.

For some reason it is not working in my site's code. I am creating the **table** using **PHP**. I thought that it could have something to do with it but if I set the **img** statically to say **100px** by **200px** the **img** is properly sized. Why is it not recognizing the parent as the **td** element which is much smaller?

After further testing with this...
If I set the **td** elements to be a static height and width then the **img** will fill the element almost fully with some space between the top and bottom of the **td** even though I've set **padding:0;** inside the **td** and **img**.

Although that works, I want to be able to configure the **td** elements to use **25%** dimensions so that the browser can do the work. So this does not really help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table {
table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This should make your cell content width same as your td width. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

Comment: This did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try placing
`<div style="clear:both"></div>`
as the last line within your `<td>` blocks.  This allows the containing element to "recognize" the dimensions of the children inside of it (in this case, your image).

Comment: This did not work. But I should also mention that the width dimension seems to be set properly of the img and just the height is going super large.